# Mule 3.5 Batch module. Enterprise or community version?

Tags: mule, batch-processing, mule-studio

I recently downloaded Mule 3.5 after having a look at the new great features coming with the Batch module. After several days developing a flow that uses Batches using Anypoint Studio, when I wanted to deploy my app to my Mule 3.5 Community standalone server I got a disagreeable surprise: neither the batch xsd was contained in the Community runtime nor the batch module jar was in the lib/module folder.

Does that mean that the Batch module belongs to the Enterprise edition? Because I cannot see any mention to that "small detail" neither in the official documentation of the module http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation..., nor in the feature comparison page http://www.mulesoft.com/platform/soa/mule-esb-enterprise

At the same time, the Community runtime for Anypoint Studio comes with the batch module, as it can be seen in the corresponding plugin folder of eclipse.

Is it a marketing strategy to force users to switch to Enterprise edition? Maybe an error in the documentation? Perhaps an error of packaging of the Community runtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Batch Module is an Enterprise feature. And you are right that is not properly documented.  For more detail on the content of each version you can take a look at the [release notes](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Mule+Release+Notes), enterprise features are listed linking an EE jira key while community ones are linking a CE jira key.

Comment: Yes it's true, buried in the release notes we can find the ticket EE-3372 Implement Batch Module. Still I don't understand why the  documentation of the Batch module doesn't say nothing about that, while in the rest of the enterprise modules is clearly stated that they belong the Enterprise edition.